# TextAlignment is being ignored in my ListView's GridViewColumn templates

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following style set for my ListView:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <!-- <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Delta, Converter=}" /> -->
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                CornerRadius="4" Margin="0,4,0,0">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                                     VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border"
                                        Value="#A5FFFFFF"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border"
                                        Value="#01FFFFFF">
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" 
                                        Value="#99B4C6"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border"
                                        Value="#c5d7e5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now amount of coercion will get my TextBlocks to right align themselves and if I set

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
```

in my Style then I'll have the reverse problem. I'm defining my templates as thus:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Bid Price">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=BidPx, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Stop putting tags in the bloody title, they do not belong there